# Use of Refresh in Windows

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-refresh

There is no such feature in Mac and Linux like **refresh** as we have in Windows, does this function has its importance in Windows system, Because they are **keeping it** from initial versions of Windows.

**Even in Windows 8** this feature has been implemented, Is this very significant in Windows system or they are just using it just as a tradition.

Since Windows 8 is much smarter than its previous versions, Developers could develop a secret/hidden implementation of refresh function, Is their any reason Why Windows supports this feature to be used by user for their own, Why not a **hidden implementation**.

Comment: What do you mean refresh? The roll-back OS refresh?

Comment: @AthomSfere I just mean Refresh that we do on Desktop, which comes as an option in a menu when we press Right Click button

Comment: How often do you actually use that? I know I never do because it does work automatically almost all the time...

Comment: @AthomSfere I use it as an old habit, whenever I feel I am free, Actually I've never seen its usefulness in my system, that's why today I asked this question, What is the use of this function in all Windows versions.

Comment: It's there just in case something doesn't work.

Comment: My linux desktop has refresh.  It's usually in the menus, but if you desire you can usually add it to a toolbar.  It's just rarely needed.  Mac OS X has it too, same kind of deal... rarely needed.  Personally, I'd say Windows is the borken one, since it often needs a refresh to display new content in a folder or whatnot. :)  Not saying linux or osx is better, mind you, just that it's rarely needed, so not as prominent as in windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The refresh is a hidden implementation already. The desktop and every other folder contains a hidden thumbnails.ini folder that gets updated with settings, icons, and files / shortcuts etc. when a change takes place.

Sometimes (Although rarely) something does not happen right, or you might want to resort a folder with the newest items added (Say on a network share). You can use refresh to force this to happen, if the windows hooks for some reason do not work as expected.

Windows has gotten much better with this auto-refresh, but nothing is more frustrating than moving a file and not seeing it, a quick refresh will confirm the file is there or that you didn't move it where you thought you did.